# Tkinter Button opacity

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new in the GUI development. I have already tried the opacity attribute but it didn't work. What I would like to do is to create a "transparent" button. There is a canvas behind the button which contains a shape and whenever I click this "invisible" button, the shape will change. I am testing prior to my project

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, be more specific and show what you've tried (make a MWE with code you've tried).

Comment: I'm sorry for being vague in my question. Thank you for your suggestion. Have a good day, Sir

Comment: Why do you need a button? Can't you let the user just click directly on the shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object on the canvas and then bind it to the desired callback as in this example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.pack()
r = c.create_rectangle((50, 50, 100, 100), fill='red')
c.tag_bind(r, '<Button-1>', lambda event: print('works'))
root.mainloop()
```

You can add more objects (e.g. rectangles, text) to the canvas to draw your button, or just draw your button in a graphics editor and use that image file as your canvas object.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your time. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Vindex - You can help future readers determine at a glance that this answer solved the issue by accepting it (with the check mark below its score).